# XSLT Need Help converting XML to show the value and the attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

My first post here but here goes,

I have an XML Document that is output from our Scanning system that looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT>  
<DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Company">LR</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Contract Code">L1935</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Entry Date">2016-11-14</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Order Account">04060</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Order Raised By">Jonathan Banks</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Order Total">358</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Purchase Order Date">2016-11-14</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Purchase Order ID">PC022987-1</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Supplier Code">04060</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="Supplier Name">Dynahurst Limited</DOCUMENTINDEX>
  <DOCUMENTINDEX Name="VAT">71.6</DOCUMENTINDEX>
</DOCUMENT>>
```

I need it to look like the below,

```
<COMPANY>LR</COMPANY>
<CONTRACT CODE>L1935</CONTRACT CODE>
```

ETC ETC ....

I am trying to use XSLT to sort this and so far have managed to pull out the Name part but i can't get the value.

My script so far looks like ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//DOCUMENTINDEX"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DOCUMENTINDEX">
    <br/><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Does anyone know how i can do this transformation as a template so i can input this into the scanning software to allow it to transform the document output as they are scanned onto the system.

Which gives me the following output.

```
Company
Contract Code
Entry Date
Order Account
Order Raised By
Order Total
Purchase Order Date
Purchase Order ID
Supplier Code
Supplier Name
VAT
```

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helo !

You can get value of currently processed element with:

`<xsl:value-of select="."/>`

XML Element name is not valid with whitespaces so you can remove them with:

`translate(./@Name,' ','')`

You can create XML element with constructor where you provide its name:

`<xsl:element name="{translate(./@Name,' ','')}"/>`

Final code will look like this:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//DOCUMENTINDEX"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="DOCUMENTINDEX">
        <xsl:element name="{translate(./@Name,' ','')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Filip this got us on the right track a few tweeks and we now have it working the way we want. Thank you so much for your help !!! Thanks

Comment: No problem :) !

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_'" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="DOCUMENTINDEX">
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="@Name" />
            <xsl:element name="{translate($name, $smallcase, $uppercase)}"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note that you cannot have spaces in the element names. Thus, in the process of transformation, I am replacing them with underscores `_`